# How do you move a UIToolBar frame relevant to the Keyboard? Objective-C

Tags: ios, keyboard, frame

So I'm not sure why my code isn't working. When the keyboard appears it puts the toolBar above the keyboard, but much higher than the height of the keyboard. Also the quick text bar in ios8 messes it up even more when I toggle it on and off, and the toolBar doesn't adjust correctly. Also when I close out the keyboard the first time the toolBar goes back to its original position, but then after once it doesn't go back down all the way where it was originally. I logged out self.yPositionStore and it never changes, which is why I don't understand why it doesn't always go back to the same spot. I've literally been working on this code all day trying to find a solution to my textfield getting hidden by the keyboard and it's giving me a headache. someone PLEASE help me.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.yPositionStore = self.toolBar.frame.origin.y;
}


- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
    CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
    CGRect newFrame = self.toolBar.frame;
    newFrame.origin.y = kbSize.height;
    self.toolBar.frame = newFrame;

}

- (void)keyboardWillBeHidden:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    CGRect newFrame = self.toolBar.frame;
    newFrame.origin.y = self.yPositionStore;
    self.toolBar.frame = newFrame;

}
```

Comment: Are you using autolayout?

Comment: yes, right now I'm trying to use different code and the frame seems to be unpredictable...

Answer (score 0):

> There was problem in keyboardwasshown method. you have to subtract toolbar height and keyboard height from main screen height to find exact y value for toolbar.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.yPositionStore = self.toolBar.frame.origin.y;
}

- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
    CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
    CGRect newFrame = self.toolBar.frame;
    newFrame.origin.y = [UIScreen mainscreen].bounds.size.height - kbSize.height - newFrame.size.height;
    self.toolBar.frame = newFrame;

}

- (void)keyboardWillBeHidden:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    CGRect newFrame = self.toolBar.frame;
    newFrame.origin.y = self.yPositionStore;
    self.toolBar.frame = newFrame;

}
```

Comment: It's going above the keyboard now but there's still a couple things, 1) there's a delay before it goes above the keyboard which I don't know why. 2) when I toggle the preidct text thing it doesn't adjust until the second time it's toggled, and it moves the tool bar up if i toggle the predict text off and the tool bar moves down if i toggle the predict text on. Also after I hide the keyboard after toggling the predict text, the tool bar doesnt move down all the way.

Comment: Do you know if there's a way in keyBoardWillBeHidden that I can get the toolBar back to its original position without using a the self.yPositionStore variable?

Comment: you have to set the frame of toolbar to set back to its original place. i guess no direct alternative.

Comment: `var newFrame = self.navigationController?.toolbar.frame; newFrame?.origin.y = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height - (newFrame?.height)!; self.navigationController?.toolbar.frame = newFrame!` @joe

Answer (score 0):

ok so for the most part this winded up working

```
- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    self.yPositionStore = self.toolBar.frame.origin.y;

    NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
    CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;

    CGRect newFrame = self.toolBar.frame;
    newFrame.origin.y = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height - kbSize.height - newFrame.size.height;
    self.toolBar.frame = newFrame;
}

- (void)keyboardWillBeHidden:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    CGRect newFrame = self.toolBar.frame;
    NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
    CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
    newFrame.origin.y += kbSize.height - newFrame.size.height;
    self.toolBar.frame = newFrame;
}
```

After the first time the keyboard is hidden, the tool bar goes down about a pixel further than it's suppose to, but it still looks good. The other problem I'm still having is on keyboardWasShown, the toolbar is repositioning itself but it's a little bit delayed, and I'm not sure how to fix that. Now off to trying out how to reposition a tableview with the keyboard!

Comment: You're checking in wasShown, which is fired after the keyboard is presented. Try checking in the `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` method